# Why would we need to convert a long into a byte. Is there any example of that approach in the real world?

Tags: java, casting

I have doubt in  Type casting in java. In type casting we can convert long type value into Byte. What is the purpose of converting long to byte in java, if there is any Real time Example for this.   eg:

```
long l=1000;
byte b=(byte)l;
System.out.println(b);
```

The output is -24. Here 1000 is converted into -24, where this conversion used in real projects.

Comment: You could ask the same thing about most narrowing casts, there's nothing special about the long/byte combination. It just comes up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well imagine you have an object lets say a Color, that is an integer (32 bits wide) that object is holding a RGBA information, now you need to get only the 1st byte because only the alpha part is relevant to you...

```
int myColor = 999;
byte alpha = (byte)myColor;
```

now alpha is -25, the fact that 999 is now turned into -25 is not relevant at all, the point is that that cast is actually [masking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)) and truncating the not relevant information,

> 999 = 0000_0011_1110_0111
>
> -25 = 1110_0111

Answer (score 3):

Here is a real world example:

```
 public byte[] longToBytes(long l) {
     byte[] bytes = new byte[8];
     bytes[0] = (byte)(l >> 56);
     bytes[1] = (byte)(l >> 48);
     // ...
     bytes[7] = (byte)(l);
     return bytes;
 }
```

The purpose of this code is self-evident ... and it won't compile without the typecast.